# Getting c2[i].push is not a function when I attempt to insert value to my array. Please let me know what is the error in my code. Thank you

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

```
function numless(maxarray){   //maxarray is a series of positive numbers
let c = [];
let c2 = [maxarray.length];  // two dimension array
for (let i=0;i<maxarray.length;i++){  //3 7 9
    let count = 0;
    for(let j=0;j<maxarray.length;j++){   //7 9
        if(maxarray[i]===maxarray[j]){
            continue;
        }
        if(maxarray[i]<maxarray[j]){
            count++;
            c2[i].push(maxarray[j]);  //want to store numbers that are less than the max array[i]. 
                                            //Getting error here.
        }
     c.push(count);
    }
}
```

This is a program to find and list the number of smaller elements in a given array.

I'm just trying to insert numbers that are less than maxarray[i] to the array c2 that is a multi-dimensional array of length same as the length of maxarray.

I'm getting the below error:
TypeError: c2[i].push is not a function.

Please let me know what is wrong here, and how to pass this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have an example of input and expected output from this code?

Comment: maxarray = [3,7,9], c should be [2,1,0] and c2 needs to store list of number less than each value. [[7,9],[9],[0]]. SOrry for my bad explanation

Comment: No worries! Whenever something isn't working as you expect, it's a good idea to use [`console.log(variable)`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_console_log.asp) so you can see if a variable is what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```js
function numless(maxarray) { //maxarray is a series of positive numbers
  let c = [];
  let c2 = []; //two dimension array
  for (let i = 0; i < maxarray.length; i++) { //3 7 9
    let count = 0;
    
    c2.push([]);
    
    for (let j = 0; j < maxarray.length; j++) { //7 9
      if (maxarray[i] === maxarray[j]) {
        continue;
      }
      if (maxarray[i] < maxarray[j]) {
        count++;
        c2[i].push(maxarray[j]); //want to store numbers that are less than the max array[i].
      }
    }
    
    if(c2[i].length === 0) { //add 0 if there are no matches
      c2[i].push(0);
    }
    
    c.push(count);
  }
  
  console.log("c", c); //expected [2,1,0]
  console.log("c2", c2); //expected [[7,9],[9],[0]]
}

numless([3,7,9]);
```

The error was because a new array needs to be created in `c2` for each index of `i` before a value can be pushed to it. Also, pushing the count to `c` needs to be added for each `i` only. After those small changes, it gives the expected output.